# how to combine different controller name with other controller action? Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, url, routes

I want to achieve such function.
So I have products controller, that handles product CRUD.
And also I have categories controller, that handles category CRUD.

What I want to achieve is that when I am browsing products show action, at the browsing bar I can see such url

```
www.mydomainname.com/products/category_name/product_name
```

At this moment I have.

```
www.mydomainname.com/products/city-skid-7v3
```

So It means I need to combine 2 controllers in routes. Does somebody have example or suggestions to start with ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should have in your `routes.rb`:

```
namespace :products do
  resources :categories do
    resources :products
  end

  # to index products without category:
  resources :products, only: :index
end
```

Then you should change all places in `views/controllers` where you used your routes. For example, if you have

```
link_to product.name, product
```

you should replace it with:

```
link_to product.name, [:products, product.category, product]
```

since now when linking to product, you also need to specify category url segment.

In your `products#index`, you can now check if `category_id` is provided and filter products respectively:

```
scope = if params[:category_id]
  Category.find_by_permalink!(params[:category_id])
else
  Product
end
@products = scope.all # add your other scopes here
```

Comment: In what way I should change views and controllers ? Sorry I am learning still.Thanks

Comment: How do your current `routes.rb` look like?

Comment: `Darbs::Application.routes.draw do
  get "about_us/index"

    root :to => 'home#index'
namespace :products do
  resources :categories do
    resources :products
  end
end
  devise_for :admin_users, ActiveAdmin::Devise.config
  ActiveAdmin.routes(self)
  resources :news


  get "about/index"

#  get "contacts/index"

  get "home/index"
  match "/products/search" => "products#search"

  

  get "panel/index"

  match "/contacts", to: "contacts#index"
  match "/home", to: "home#index"
   match "/about_us", to: "about_us#index"
    match "/news", to: "news#index"
  resources :manufacturers



`

Comment: At this moment I cannot user resources:products route, so How can I get to work products/index path?

Comment: You want to index product without category?

Comment: .Yes, so there would be list off al products. but when I click on specific product then the function above comes in .

Comment: Right. I forgot it's namespaced. Edit was made again and your helpers are now similar to `products_category_product_path` etc.

Comment: Now I get this error, `No route matches {:action=>"show", :controller=>"products/products"}
`  Why I get such multiplied products/products controller ? :(

Comment: Because your `products_controller` is namespaced with `products`. You get this error because somewhere you try to link or redirect to `products` without specifying `category` probably.